# How to use grant on and agreed on

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Is it correct if I use "grant on" instead of "agreed on"? I wrote:

> It means all the standard setters around the world should **grant on** a specific, high quality accounting standard.

I just want to know is this sentence correct?

Comment: What makes you think _grant on_ is acceptable? Have you seen this anywhere before?

Comment: I think it's confused with "agree on" but "grant" doesn't have quite the same shades of meaning as "agree".

Answer (score 1):

As per [*this*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grant) link, "grant" is a transitive verb, which means it should be associated with a direct object. So "grant on" is definitely not a valid phrase.

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Comment: Several things. I think you had meant to link to [grant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grant), not *transitive*. Also, there *is* a direct object in the question: *a specific, high quality accounting standard.* Finally, the phrase *carry on* doesn't require a direct object, so, even if there weren't one here, why couldn't you say something like *keep calm and* ***grant on***?

Comment: Oh yes, I've edited it. Isn't *a specific, high quality accounting standard* an indirect object here, on account of the preposition? When someone says *He granted*, I'd generally expect them to follow it with some direct object, like *He granted my request*.